# Char to Char[1024] error - UDP Internet Protocol

Tags: c++, udp

Code:

```
int SendDG(char TOSEND, int IRES, SOCKET SSOCK, sockaddr_in RADD)
    {
        char Data[1024]=TOSEND;
        int BufLen = 1024;
        int iResult = IRES;
        SOCKET SendSocket = SSOCK;
        sockaddr_in RecvAddr = RADD;
           //---------------------------------------------
        // Send a datagram to the receiver
        wprintf(L"Sending info to the receiver...\n");
        iResult = sendto(SendSocket,
                         Data, BufLen, 0, (SOCKADDR *) & RecvAddr, sizeof (RecvAddr));
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            wprintf(L"sendto failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(SendSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Errors:

> IntelliSense: initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate
>   object error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char' to
>   'char [1024]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to send the contents of `TOSEND` (as it appears to be the case in your code), then:

1. Get rid of this:

   `char Data[1024]=TOSEND;`

   `int BufLen = 1024;`
2. Change this:

   `iResult = sendto(SendSocket, Data, BufLen, ...);`

   to `iResult = sendto(SendSocket, &TOSEND, sizeof(TOSEND), ...);`

Answer (score 1):

A question would have been nice.

But I guess: in the third line you write:

```
char Data[1024]=TOSEND;
```

where `Data` is an `char`-array and `TOSEND` is a plain `char`. And so you cannot assign a plain `char` to a `char` array. Might be that you want something like

```
char Data[1024];
Data[0] = TOSEND;
```

But I don't think so. I assume that the `TOSEND` should some kind of pointer that points to the data that should be sent.

Answer (score 0):

use `strcpy(Data,TOSEND);` instead of `Data[1024]=TOSEND`
hope it solves the problem.

Comment: yeah, sorry you are correct. But now the question arises that if `TOSEND` is not a pointer to a null-terminated string then what is the use of copying it to Data[1024]? i mean it may be copied to only Data. Please correct me because i'm a little confused. Thanx